# How do I run an app using the power button

Tags: android, custom-action, power-management

I have been around browsing tutorials for android power button mods, I have a couple of questions in this regard Those being:

1. How do I set a specific timer to make my app run after the button as been depressed for say 5 seconds.
2. How do I make my app run at start up.

The basic premise of it being a personal security app(So you are not thinking I am doing anything stupid with it.). I am trying to give it easy access as well as quick functionality.

Any tips would be wonderful.
-Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any advantage to using the power button - in fact, only pitfalls. What are you going to do about the issue of some phones (HTC devices particularly come to mind, no doubt many more) that use the power button being depressed for several seconds to bring up a menu? If a user wants easy access to your application they can put it onto their home screen, or create shortcuts on locks screens etc on some devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set a specific timer to make my app run after the button as been depressed for say 5 seconds.

This is not supported.

> How do I make my app run at start up.

If your "app" has a UI that is supposed to "run at start up", make it be the home screen.

If, instead, you are trying to do something else (e.g., schedule `AlarmManager` events), register a `BroadcastReceiver` for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action in the manifest, and have the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

Comment: Basically what I am looking to do is have the app loaded at startup so all the user has to do is press and hold the button a little longer then it requires for the menu to come up so that it runs the app in question. If by any chance you have a better and more easy idea to get this done that does not require the user having to fish through screens to run the app then by all means please do tell. Its intended to be use by kids who have worried parents so all they need to do is press the button and it calls home with a message of "I will be a little late don't wait up for me" kind of thing.

Comment: @a.kollar: What you want is not supported.